Checklist of documents for visiting Poland if I already have a Schengen visa
I am an Indian national doing a PhD in the UK. I intend to visit Poland next week for an academic conference. Earlier this year, I obtained a short-stay Schengen visa to attend a summer school in Germany, and the visa is still valid. While applying for the visa, I was given a long checklist of items I needed for the visa process. This included: my return tickets, hotel bookings, proof of student status, letter of invitation, travel insurance, etc. Since I didn't have to go through the visa process again, I am wondering which items on the checklist am I still expected to carry with me? At German immigration I was asked to show my return tickets and hotel bookings only, so these would probably be best to have on my person at the airport. What other documents should I be carrying with me?
Edit: I was asked for the following at the border- invitation letter from conference organisers, proof of accomodation, and return tickets to the UK.

Just to be sure: the visa is multi-entry? You meet both the duration (number of days) and validity (start/end dates) requirements? Your stay in Poland wouldn't make you exceed the 90/180 limit? I suppose it is a type C visa?

@jcaron Yes, all these requirements are met. I specifically asked the German embassy for  a multi-entry, stating that I intend to visit Poland in September.


Since I didn't have to go through the visa process again, I am wondering which items on the checklist am I still expected to carry with me?

In theory, all of them are fair game for the border guards to ask about. Your visa is only valid as long as you still fulfill the requirements and since you need a visa to enter the Schengen area, a failure to satisfy any of these requirements is a valid reason to refuse entry (and revoke the visa).

At German immigration I was asked to show my return tickets and hotel bookings only, so these would probably be best to have on my person at the airport. What other documents should I be carrying with me?

You primarily want to establish

where you are going and why (a coherent explanation can be enough, hotel booking, tickets, invitation, etc. add credibility)
that you have planned to return to your country of residence

As the hotel and flight are the main things that change from one trip to the next, they are especially relevant for you and since the conference is the main reason to go, I would also print out any registration confirmation you may have. At the same time, since you have demonstrated your reliability by using your visa for a first trip, border guards might not even want to see that and might be content with a verbal explanation.
By contrast, the details regarding your status or financial situation have already been assessed when applying for the visa and do not change so quickly so there is really no need for the border guards to double-check them. But as I wrote earlier, they are allowed to ask about anything.

In practice: Have hotel and return flight at hand, if event requires a ticket have that too, be prepared to explain and show more information on the event. Showing from phone is fine, but printouts can be better. Sadly those of us with worse passports do get asked for proof more than those with better passports, even if our travel history and country of residence paints a different picture.
